# Atualizar Chart com dados de uma coluna no GridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Tenho em meu projeto um GridView onde insiro manualmente dados na ultima coluna (índice 7) e um PieChart que deve se atualizar de acordo com essa ultima coluna, entretanto, por mais que consiga pegar os dados da coluna não consigo passa-los para o Chart. Segue código onde capturo os valore:

```
TimeSpan[] permanencia = new TimeSpan[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            permanencia[i] = TimeSpan.Parse(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value));
        }
```

Até aqui tudo certo, mas quando tento passar os dados pra atualizar meu Chart, nada acontece. Segue código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ds = new DataSet(Convert.ToString(permanencia[i]));
            chart1.DataSource = ds;
            chart1.DataBind();
            chart1.Update();
        }
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Sou iniciante com Charts...

Obs: estou trabalhando com WindowsForm e como já dito, os dados desta coluna são gerados manualmente...

A pedido, segue código de preenchimento da ultima coluna, a **UNICA** preenchida desta maneira...

```
// CALCULO DA PERMANÊNCIA E INSERÇÃO DA COLUNA COM OS RESPECTIVOS DADOS
        DateTime ent = new DateTime();
        DateTime sad = new DateTime();
        TimeSpan permanencia = new TimeSpan();
        DataGridViewRow l = dataGridView1.Rows[0];
        DataGridViewCell c = l.Cells[0];
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("colunaPermanencia", "Permanencia");

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ent = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
            sad = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
            permanencia = sad - ent;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["colunaPermanencia"].Value = permanencia.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Para um chart, você tem que informar dados de linhas...colunas... eixos X,Y,Z enfim, vários dados... esse comando ds = new DataSet(Convert.ToString(permanencia[i])); acredito que nem irá funcionar

Comment: mostre como você preenche todo o gridview

Comment: Pronto. Editei a pergunta com o código

Comment: eu me referia a como você preenche todos os dados da gridview, todas as colunas

Comment: e quais serão os dados que deverão aparecer no Chart ? tempo de permanencia e mais qual ?

Comment: Eu to usando conexão com o MySql e puxando os outros dados de lá. Somente essa coluna está diferente

Comment: Tempo de permanencia e o nome do curso

Comment: usa um DataSet / DataTable que vem do mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que você está utilizando DataTable como fonte de dados do seu dataGridView, acho que há um problema em adicionar uma coluna manualmente ao controle, e preeche-lá com os dados, pois ela não será adicionada ao DataTable.

Sugiro que faça esse cálculo diretamente no comando SQL e a coluna já seja retornada para o DataTable. Evitando todo esse código no seu Form.

Em seguida basta utilizar o mesmo DataTable como DataSource do Chart, definindo qual será o eixo X e Y da Série que adicionar a ele.

Fiz um código de exemplo: (Obs. A parte dos dados foram simuladas)

```
//Simulação da fonte de dados
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("curso");
dt.Columns.Add("permanencia");
Random rnd = new Random();
//Insere dados aleatórios na tabela
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    DataRow r1 = dt.NewRow();
    r1["curso"] = "Curso " + i;
    r1["permanencia"] = Math.Round(new TimeSpan(0, rnd.Next(50), rnd.Next(50)).TotalMinutes,2);
    dt.Rows.Add(r1);
}

//Fonte do DataGridView
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
//Fonte do Chart
chart1.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
//A Serie 0 já é adicionada quando você arrasta o controle para o Form
//Essas configurações podem ser feitas na interface visual
chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "curso"; //Define o eixo X
chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "permanencia"; //Defino o eixo Y 


chart1.DataBind();
```

Mais informações sobre Chart:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

http://www.macoratti.net/12/11/c_chart1.htm

Comment: Me ajudou muito a resolver o problema. Muito obrigado..